# Can't associate SSMS 2016 to .sql Files

Tags: windows-7, file-association, sql, file-extension, ssms

I recently installed SSMS 2016 on my windows 7 machine.  When I view a directory of .sql files, I notice that they all have a text file icon image for them and the file type is simply "SQL File".  When I right click and choose Open With -> Choose Default Program, SSMS is not in the list.  Below is a screen shot of what I see:

[image]

When I expand Other Programs, the below is what is shown:

[image]

Since I don't see SSMS listed, I choose to browse.  Since this is SSMS 2016, I browse to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe".  However, once I choose that, it takes me back to the window seen in the above screen shot, and SSMS is not listed as an option.  I have tried different programs to try and clear any file associations with .sql and no luck yet.  Right now, if I double click a .sql file, it will open in Notepad (probably because I accidentally choose it from the open with window by accident at some point).

Anybody have any ideas how to get this associated with SSMS?

Comment: If you expand "other programs" which programs are listed?

Comment: @Ramhound, I have edited the question to show a screenshot of the other programs.

Comment: [ftype](https://ss64.com/nt/ftype.html) followed by [assoc](https://ss64.com/nt/assoc.html) should do the trick.

Comment: @DavidPostill, can you provide an example using those commands?  I have tried and no dice so far, not sure if I am entering something wrong perhaps?

Comment: `ftype sqlfile="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe" "%1"` followed by `assoc .sql=sqlfile`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I entered that in and rebooted, but nothing has changed.